# How to open .docx files on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, microsoft-word, word-documents

I am unable to view images in .docx on Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 10.10 and OpenOffice.org 3.2.1 (ooo-build 3.2.1.4, Ubuntu package 1:3.2.1-7ubuntu1.1)

Is there any tool to read `.docx`? Please note that I do not have access to Google drive and cannot use any related tools.

I tried to use [DocXV.exe](http://download.cnet.com/DocX-Viewer/3000-18483_4-75179715.html) with Wine, in vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LibreOffice

[image: Install via the software center]

or Abiword

[image: Install via the software center].

Comment: Thanks! Abiword worked for my Ubuntu version, but only partially... Some images were still not viewable.

Comment: What type of images are not viewable? Are you sure your file is not corrupt? Just asking.

Comment: It is a state machine  and flow chart kind of image. I am not sure about its format.

Comment: Aah. It might be native office format. Something like visio....

Comment: Maybe. So native office formats like visio are not supported on Ubuntu OOO?